# Shell interpreter Escape special character $

Tags: linux, shell, unix, curl, scripting

How can I escape the $ character inside my variable?
This is how my code looks

```
$var1 = value
$var2 =abc!$123
response= ‘ curl -sS -u “$var1: $var2” params api-endpoint‘ 
echo $response
```

The problem that I’m facing is $var2 is getting trimmed starting from $
Any suggestions?

Comment: Please make sure to copy&paste your code to the question instead of retyping. There are many errors in the code.

Answer (score 0):

That is due to "!" in var2 . ( ! performs history expansion )

```
[root@c3-bl460g9-81 machine]# var2=abc!$123
var2=abcvar1=value123
```

So wrap var2 assigment in ' '(single quotes) :

```
[root@c3-bl460g9-81 machine]# var2='abc!$123'
[root@c3-bl460g9-81 machine]# echo $var2
abc!$123
```

Comment: this is environment variable(password) and I don’t set this value.

Comment: is echo $var2 , showing correct output or trimmed output ? little aggressive workaround may be you think of turing off history expansion .check [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/384861/is-history-expansion-disabled-in-scripts)